# Hover submenu doesn't work

Tags: html, css, hover, submenu

I want to create a submenu, and when I hover the Cath, I want to display the Insider and the Outsider. (All the things I want to be accomplished with css)

Here is my code,but something get wrong with my code

```css
/* ALL A HOVER */
.cath:hover > ul.submenu-items {
  background:#778;
}

/* INNER UL HIDE */
.cath ul.submenu-items {
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  padding-left:20px;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  max-height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
/* INNER UL SHOW */
.cath:hover > ul.submenu-items{
  max-height:500px;
  transition: max-height 0.25s ease-in;
}
```

```html
  <div  class='wr-element-container wr-element-submenu cath' ><div class="block-sub-menu">
    <a class=" caption" title="cath"><span class=""><span class="ig-menu-title">Cath </span></span></a>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <span class="divider"></span>
    <ul class="submenu-items ">
    <li id="menu-item-1971" class="menu-item-1971"><a>Inside</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1972" class="menu-item-1972"><a >Outside</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `>` selector and it will work just fine.

the `>` selector only works on direct children, your element is not a direct child of **cath**, which means you need to use space instead.

```
.cath:hover  ul.submenu-items{
      ....
    }
```

**See code snippet:**

```css
/* ALL A HOVER */
.kathetou:hover > ul.submenu-items {
  background:#778;
}

/* INNER UL HIDE */
.cath  ul.submenu-items {
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  padding-left:20px;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  max-height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
/* INNER UL SHOW */
.cath:hover  ul.submenu-items{
  max-height:500px;
  transition: max-height 0.25s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div  class='wr-element-container wr-element-submenu cath' ><div class="block-sub-menu">
    <a class=" caption" title="cath"><span class=""><span class="ig-menu-title">Cath </span></span></a>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <span class="divider"></span>
    <ul class="submenu-items ">
    <li id="menu-item-1971" class="menu-item-1971"><a>Inside</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1972" class="menu-item-1972"><a >Outside</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```